# Join two datasets based on a flag and id

Tags: join, sas, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

I am trying to join two datasets based on a flag and id.
i.e

```
proc sql;
create table demo as
select a.*,b.b1,b.2
from table1 a
left join table2 on
(a.flag=b.flag and a.id=b.id) or (a.flag ne b.flag and a.id=b.id)
end;
```

This code runs into a loop and never produces a output.
I want to make sure that where there are flag values matching get the attributes; if not get the attributes at id level so that we do not have blank values.

Comment: Please consider providing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your ON condition is just A.ID=B.ID.  Perhaps in other SQL implementation that use tri-level logic  there is a possibility that missing (aka null) values of FLAG in either dataset would cause the expression to not be just A.ID=B.ID.  But SAS only uses binary logic.  Values are either the same or they aren't even if one or both are missing.

Comment: I see that you forgot 'b' on the line 'left join table2 on'. Rewrite it : left join table2 b on

Answer (score 1):

This join condition cannot be optimized. It is not a good practice to use `or` in a join. If you check your log, you'll see this:

```
NOTE: The execution of this query involves performing one or more Cartesian product joins 
that can not be optimized.
```

Instead, transform your query to do a union:

```
proc sql;
    create table demo as
        select a.*,
               b.b1,
               b.b2
        from table1 as a
        left join 
             table2 as b
        on a.flag=b.flag and a.id=b.id

        UNION

        select a.*,
               b.b1,
               b.b2
        from table1 as a
        left join 
             table2 as b
        on a.flag ne b.flag and a.id=b.id
    ;
quit;
```